# What is a right way to generate the Certificates while using FCM

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, apple-developer-account

I am amazed to see that When ever I am creating Certificates **"Apple Push Notification service SSL (Production & Development)"** it is not shown in Profiles

Things are very much changed on Developer portal And after bashing my head many times (deleting and creating different certificates) its is not working for me

**What I am doing:**
Attempt 1:  When I create certificates from **certificate menu** it did appear on Profile menu (from where we create provisioning profile & selects certificates) but when I create APNs SSL certificate it never appears in provisioning profile menu

Attempt 2: I created separate SSL certificate and created p12 file from them and uploaded them into FCM server and then i created normal certificate and generated Provisioning profile and installing them in xcode it gives me error of not including something for Notification.

So after trying all these I am now not able to run app on device and not able to work around for FCM notification

**Question:** What steps are needed to create certificate while working on FCM?

**"NOTE: Since all interface and working procedures are updated on developer portal is updated so all help on SO and other places are out date. Please let me know what should I do and how it is done in precise manner it will be great help. THANKS"**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use for push notification, .p8  key because this same key will work for both sandbox And production mode.

[Use this solution to generate .p8 Key And upload key on firebase read this articles](https://fluffy.es/p8-push-notification/)